# Why Datastore Admin API export/import is not available in APIs explorer?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-datastore, google-apis-explorer

Does anyone know why the Datastore Admin API `export` and `import` operations are not available with APIs explorer?

Just visit the [API page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects/export).

Meanwhile the API for getting long-running operations [is available](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects.operations/get).

[image: Error initializing the APIs Explorer]

Answer (score 5):

We've had a delay pushing the configuration changes to make it appear in the explorer. [Working on it!]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because the recently added export/import functionality is still being polished.

The  `!` badges with a `New!` popup when hovering over are still visible in the [Exporting and Importing Entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) left-side navigation bar:

[image]